# How to add an if condition inside id of a JSX div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, frontend, jsx

I would like to change id of a div in jsx like so :-

```
{ ['A','B','C','D'].map((element, cell) => (
    <div id="alphabet_if({element}==='A'){'ok'}else{ {element} }">
        Some
    </div>
)) }
```

But this results in

```
{ ['A','B','C','D'].map((element, cell) => (
    <div id="alphabet_if({element}==='A'){'ok'}else{ {element} }">
        Some
    </div>
)) }
```

Comment: Please do accept the answers to help the community find and learn from your questions. You can do so by clicking on the tick mark for the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

is this what you are looking for:

Sandbox for your case: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-6mwvf

```
{ ['A','B','C','D'].map((element, cell) => (
    <div id={`alphabet_${element === 'A' ? 'ok' : element}`}>
        Some
    </div>
)) }
```